# How to call method from separate package : Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a method from the file Duality.java to be run in Min.Java when a button is clicked. Below are the two files and what I am currently trying to do, which is not working. How do I get the method duality() to run when the button is clicked within Min.java?

Duality.java

```
package com.android.control;

import android.util.Log;
import com.map.AppName.R;

public class duality {

    public void duality(){
       Log.e("Did It Run","Yes it ran");
    }
}
```

Min.java

```
package com.android.control;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.map.AppName.R;

public class Min extends LinearLayout {

    Button but;
    private final int ELEMENT_HEIGHT = 60;
    private final int ELEMENT_WIDTH = 80;;
    private final int TEXT_SIZE = 30; 

    public Min( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet ) {
        super(context, attributeSet);   

        this.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
        LayoutParams elementParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ELEMENT_WIDTH, ELEMENT_HEIGHT );

        createBut( context );

        addView( but, elementParams );
    }

private void createButton( Context context){
        but = new Button( context );
        but.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
        but.setText( "Go" );

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Duality duality = new duality();

            }
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only *constructing an instance* of the `duality` class - you're not calling the `duality()` method on it.

This might be because you wanted that method to be a constructor - but it's not, because you specified a `void` return type, so it's just a conventional method.

(By the way, it's conventional in Java to give classes names that start with uppercase characters.  If you called your class `Duality`, there may be less chance that you'd get the two confused; though the problem with accidental non-constructors would still stand.)

Comment: Not only that, he wrote `Duality`, not `duality`.

Comment: Originally it did say `duality duality = new duality()`.  I think it was edited out of pride, in response to an early form of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Min` and `duality` are in the `com.android.control` package so they should be able to see eachother without imports.

It's recommended to capitalize class names. In fact, since your method has the same name as the class it might be conflicting with the constructor name. I suggest this:

```
public class Duality {

    public void duality(){
       Log.e("Did It Run","Yes it ran");
    }
}
```

...

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Duality d = new Duality();
         d.duality();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that the class name and file name use same case combination in names.
2. if u want to call the constructor, remove the void from:

   public void duality()
3. if it is supposed to b a function and not constructor, call it using:

   object_name.duality();
4. u r calling createBut() and have given code for createButton().. is that a mistake in copy pasting?